# What are the possible reasons for an `emit dataChanged( ... );` to not trigger view's display update?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing my 3rd "naive" model as QAbstractItemModel inheriting class.

So far it worked well.
However, I've been using read-only "static" models in my views and only changed the model of some views depending on the user's actions. So I used `my_view->setModel( a_model );` to update a view.

Now I need to have one of the views to keep a unique model but that model needs to be update sometimes, using a special function "update()" function that I call in the code when required.

At the end of the update() function, I just call `emit dataChanged( ... );` with the corresponding data.

It seems that it doesn't update the view this model is connected to. The only way to make the view update seems to do something like `my_view->setModel( nullptr );` then `my_view->setModel( a_model );` again.

**What are the possible reasons for an `emit dataChanged( ... );` to not trigger view's display update?**

I've been debugging my model implementation functions and the index() function get called but not the data(). I'm a bit worried that maybe I didn't understood something about the model/view system in the case of changing model (that is not changed through the view but programmatically).

It's an open-source project so you chan check the full model code there (it's a bit hacky I think, not used to model/view system of Qt) : http://code.google.com/p/art-of-sequence/source/browse/tools/aosdesigner/view/model/LayerObjectsModel.cpp?spec=svn4fe209aa3e82f2c7cd42192581a890e28bada9b0&r=4fe209aa3e82f2c7cd42192581a890e28bada9b0
The code of the widget managing the view is available there : http://code.google.com/p/art-of-sequence/source/browse/tools/aosdesigner/view/LayersView.cpp?spec=svn4fe209aa3e82f2c7cd42192581a890e28bada9b0&r=4fe209aa3e82f2c7cd42192581a890e28bada9b0

Comment: Have you tried to create a connection between model's signal [dataChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) and view's slot [dataChanged()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemview.html#dataChanged) explicitly?

Comment: No but I thought it was automatically done by the setModel() call but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: @webclectic There is no instructions about that : http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked a bit Qt documentation. `dataChanged()` should be emitted when existing data of the model changes.

If you are adding rows to the model check [beginInsertRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) and [endInsertRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows)

From the insertRows Qt documentation:

> If you implement your own model, you can reimplement this function if
>   you want to support insertions. Alternatively, you can provide your
>   own API for altering the data. In either case, you will need to call
>   beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() to notify other components that
>   the model has changed.

If you are removing rows from the model check correspondingly [beginRemoveRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveRows) and [endRemoveRows](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#endRemoveRows)

Also have a look at [beginResetData](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel)

> When a model radically changes its data it can sometimes be easier to
>   just call this function rather than emit dataChanged() to inform other
>   components when the underlying data source, or its structure, has
>   changed.

Comment: Thanks, using begin/endResetData does works. I didn't know changing rows did require different messages O__o